# How to display start date and date in one textbox, in addition to that month and date should be like dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datefilter"]').daterangepicker({
      autoUpdateInput: false,
      locale: {
          cancelLabel: 'Clear'
      }
    });

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('apply.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val(picker.startDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY') + ' - ' + picker.endDate.format('MM/DD/YYYY'));
    });

    $('input[name="datefilter"]').on('cancel.daterangepicker', function(ev, picker) {
        $(this).val('');
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.css"/>

<input type="text" name="datefilter" value="" class="date-selection"/>
```

And the output should be `24 Dec 2019 - 24 Nov 2019`

Both month and year should be like a dropdown as shown in the image above

Comment: Look at the url: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/daterangepicker@3.0.5/test.html . You are using JS resources from the relative url of that website. From the daterangepicker script, just replace script with below code: 

$(function() {
        $('#picker').daterangepicker({
          showDropdowns: true,
          minYear: 2014,
          maxYear: 2019,
          locale: {
            format: 'DD MMM YYYY'
          }
        });
      });